Edit Crystal Report file
I want to edit this RPT file, but I'm confused

In this file it show only a few rows, but when I copy and paste the query to SQL Server there is so many rows in there. So how does this work?
Please help, thank you
Here is the query
SELECT GL_REPORT."COMP", GL_REPORT."PERIOD", GL_REPORT."CODE", GL_REPORT."GROUPS", GL_REPORT."DESCR", GL_REPORT."SALDO", GL_REPORT."MONTHLY", GL_REPORT."BULANAN", GL_REPORT."TAHUNAN"
FROM "SUIS"."dbo"."GL_REPORT" GL_REPORT
WHERE GL_REPORT."SALDO" <> 0 AND GL_REPORT."PERIOD" = '' AND (GL_REPORT."GROUPS" = '5' OR GL_REPORT."GROUPS" = '4') AND GL_REPORT."COMP" = '01' ORDER BY GL_REPORT."COMP" ASC

I tried to change the query but I'm not brave enough to change the RPT file.

How do you expect us to assist you without additional details? All you have shown us is the report output... no report definition or query.

[edit] any clarifications into your question

So you are saying that the query shown, when run in SQL Server returns a different number of rows than when the same query is run in Crystal reports?

I just found an answer, the solution is in Field Object/Explorer. So there is condition that only show some rows, so I just edited it.
